# How do I generate or use a U2F SSH key on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, u2f

I have a security key that, when I plug it into an Ubuntu 20.04 host, can be used to generate a `sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com` key like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk
cat ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk.pub
```

How do I get the same result from a Windows machine with the same physical security key?

Comment: Note: Win32-OpenSSH is currently on release 8.1. It's possible the answer is "not yet". https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases